# Android: display a web page and letting user login to get the feedly access token

Tags: java, android, redirect, feedly

I am trying to write an Android app to access and display Feedly subscriptions to the user.

For this purpose , I need to post a URL to Feedly API and in return it send back HTML code for login page.

URL example to post:

https://sandbox7.feedly.com/v3/auth/auth?client_id=sandbox&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&scope=https://cloud.feedly.com/subscriptions&response_type=code

Here, I use http://localhost as redirect URI because I am not hosting anything for this application.

after the user logs in, Feedly API redirects a code to http://localhost

Now, I have 2 issues:
1. I don't know how to display the web page for login on Android. How can I do that and let the user login ? What is the best practice for such purpose ?
2. How can I get the access token which is sent back to the redirect URI as a parameter ?

for the first question maybe I can use webview as suggested in another question.  [How to display a webpage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725771/how-to-display-a-webpage-in-android)

BUT then how shall I get the code returning to the redirect_uri ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by calling mobile browser with correct URL:

```
String url = "http://cloud.feedly.com/v3/auth/auth?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=myownuri%3A%2F%2F&scope=https://cloud.feedly.com/subscriptions&response_type=code";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

and then fetching the redirected URL by registering a custom URI in the manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".BrowserActivity"
    android:label="Feedly Login" >
   <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="myownuri" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then I parse the returned parameter in my activity :

```
Uri data = this.getIntent().getData();
if (data != null && data.isHierarchical()) {
    String url = this.getIntent().getDataString();
```