# Is there a way to show a website or a fragment in an android widget with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, widget

I am making an app and want to make widgets. But I need to show an website in the widget. Is that even possible? If yes how can it be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a webpage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725771/how-to-display-a-webpage-in-android)

Comment: By "widget", do you mean [app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview)? If so, then the answer is no, that is not possible.

Comment: Greetings @CommonsWare, can I ask you directly about your blog and project on `gitlab` for downloading a file using `Okio` library for versions `android 10` and above? I mean I do not think I should be posting a separate question for that? :)

Comment: @mehulbisht: "I mean I do not think I should be posting a separate question for that? :)" -- there are a bunch of questions on SO of the form "hey, I saw this technique in this blog post and had some questions about it". So long as the question can stand alone and does not completely rely on the blog post existing (in case my site goes *poof*), it should be a perfectly fine SO question.

Comment: okay, will create a question then :)